# sed -i - edit files in place does not work in compound commandq

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, find

having this command:

```
$ find / -path /home/oldroot -prune -o -name config.yml -exec sed -i'' '/(swipe)|(pinch)/s/[0-9].*/1/' {} \+
```

won't edit:

```
couldn't open temporary file /home/shepherd/.config/fusuma/sedSQVSZd: Permission denied
```

You can say, it does not work because of sudo. But it does not even work with sudo, the point is the `-i` flag here.
`find` found file `/fusuma/config.yml`, but `-i` change it into `/fusuma/sedSQVSZd` as sideeffect of in-place edditing. So is there a way to persist filenames with sed?

Comment: The issue is in creating the temporary file that `sed` writes the result of the edits into before replacing the original file (this is how "in-place" editing works). The user running `sed` does not have permission to create the temporary file in that location. Can you show the permissions and ownerships on `/home/shepherd/.config/fusuma`, `/home/shepherd/.config`, `/home/shepherd` and `/home` and let us know what user is executing that command?

Comment: all of them are own by me, except of `/home/`, which is as usual owned by root. The command is run by sudo privileges

Comment: but I am not sure these information are needed for clarification of sed command

Comment: `sed -i` is non-standard and thus not grated to be supported anyway.

Comment: @Herdsman Well, I was just wondering if there was a permission, extended attribute, ACL, or something else that would prevent either your own user or root writing to the directory. In any case, the filename that you see in the error message is the name of the _temporary file_ that `sed` uses internally. It has nothing to do with the filename of your file other than that is located in the same directory.

Comment: @Kusalananda i know, the issue is caused by sed `-i` that creates temporary file to edit "inplace", but should not the sed command manage to change it back? From the temporary file it created to the name of the original file? (I suppose, as ohterwise, how would it edit "inplace" without changing the name back), so is it internal problem of sed, or can I somewho fix that? (That is - used inpace edditing without worry about temporary files - or better - sed command is so advanced, it could change it back for me). So how to do that?

Comment: The issue is not changing the name of the temporary file to replace the original. The issue is creating the temporary file in the first place.

Comment: @Kusalananda but that is inner mechanism of `sed`, how can I do something? And - in normal cases, it works no matter creating temporary file in the first place. But suddenly, when piped of I do not know the cause - it has problem with creating temporary file in the first place. Is not it a little strange?

Comment: If you think that it's the pipe causing problem, did you try running that `sed` command without the pipe on the file directly?  `sed -i'' '/(swipe)|(pinch)/s/[0-9].*/1/'  /home/shepherd/.config/fusuma/config.yml`

Comment: Is this question still an open issue for you?